# OpenRefine - Spilt cells after last whitespace

Tags: openrefine

I don't know how to split these lines with Open Refine:

ABGB: Praxiskommentar Schwimann/?Kodek
AHG Amtshaftungsgesetz: Praxiskommentar Ziehensack

--> so I have the values like this:

| Title | Author |
| --- | --- |
| ABGB: Praxiskommentar | Schwimann/?Kodek |
| AHG Amtshaftungsgesetz: Praxiskommentar | Ziehensack |

I already tried it with the grel expression value.split(' ')[-1] but with this I'm only getting the author names.
Can anybody help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please use some formatting like tables (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) in your example to better show what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are already on the right track.

So you first [add a new column](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/columnediting#add-column-based-on-this-column) **Author** with the GREL expression `value.split(' ')[-1]`.

You then have to remove the author from the **Title** column using the [transform dialog](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#transform).

**Solution using [GREL arrays](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#array-functions):**

For this solution we are again splitting the `value` using whitespace.
The tricky part is then to remove the last element from the array.
For this we have to bind the array to a variable `a` using [with](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grel#withe1-variable-v-e2). After that we can calculate the [length of the array](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#lengtha) and reduce it by one. This enables us to [get](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#geta-n-from-n-to-optional) only the title elements from the array. We then use [join](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#joina-sep) to write the remaining array values back as string.

```
with(value.split(' '), a, a.get(0, a.length()-1)).join(' ')
```

**Solution using [replace](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#replaces-s-or-p-find-s-replace):**

A more intuitive solution is to directly replace the value from the colum **Author** in the column **Title**.
This solution is more prone to errors as it will also replace the name of the author if it is part of the title.

```
value.replace(row.cells["Author"].value, "").trim()
```